# bash: command substitution:syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Tags: java, linux, bash, jsch

I am using a simple command to change password for user in remote linux machine by using Java Jsch code.
My command is

```
command = "echo -ne "+userPassword+" \n echo "+userPassword+" \n | smbpasswd -a -s "+userId;
((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' "+command);
```

But it is returning error saying,

> ```
> bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
> bash: command substitution: line 2: ` | smbpasswd -a -s TestUserNew'
>
> sudo: JX7MuQoTJX7MuQoT: command not found
> ```

I am confused here as this command runs in Linux. Can someone please help me fix this?

Thanks,
Gourab

Comment: First thing I'd do is System.out.println(command); immediately before you try to execute the command

Comment: command: sudo -S -p '' echo -ne jDCMBv6W 

 jDCMBv6W 

 | smbpasswd -a -s TestUserNew

Comment: I got the above output @DaveH

Comment: Remove the '\n' before `| smbpasswd`

Comment: and if you paste that output in to a linux shell, does it work?

Comment: I have already tried removing '\n' before | but did not work. @NicholasK

Comment: I have changed the command to the following, but still now showing different error,

command: sudo -S -p '' echo -ne IxXwe3kS
IxXwe3kS | smbpasswd -a -s TestUserNew

Comment: IxXwe3kSbash: line 1: IxXwe3kS: command not found
When run by root:
    smbpasswd [options] [username]
otherwise:
    smbpasswd [options]
@DaveH

Comment: Not working in linux shell @DaveH

Answer (score 0):

This command works on the command line:

```
(echo "wxfLW2qJ"; echo "wxfLW2qJ") | sudo smbpasswd tester
```

Note that `sudo` is used for the `smbpasswd` command. Furthermore the brackets around the first part create a subshell which seems to be important.

Comment: Hi,
I do not have old password here so I modified the code a bit,

String command = "(echo \"" + userPassword + "\"; echo \"" + userPassword + "\") | smbpasswd " + userId;

And it is showing below error,

bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

bash: -c: line 0: `sudo -S -p '' (echo "wxfLW2qJ"; echo "wxfLW2qJ") | smbpasswd TestUserNew' 
@Nan

Comment: Also I am creating smbpassword here.

Comment: I changed the code accordingly,
command: sudo -S -p '' (echo "CQGqlv7B"; echo "CQGqlv7B") | sudo smbpasswd TestUserNew

Comment: But received the following error,

bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `sudo -S -p '' (echo "CQGqlv7B"; echo "CQGqlv7B") | sudo smbpasswd TestUserNew'

Comment: @Gourab Banerjee: Remove the first sudo.

Comment: Removing sudo from the beginning of the line is not working.

Output:
echo -e "7YOxmR6R7YOxmR6R" | smbpasswd -a TestUserNew

Comment: When run by root:
    smbpasswd [options] [username]
otherwise:
    smbpasswd [options]

Comment: @Gourab Banerjee: Seems to be a problem with your java code.

Comment: It may be problem in code but if I can create the command which can create/update the password for a user in a single line then the this issue will be as good as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

Original code is,

`command = "echo -ne \""+userPassword+"\n"+userPassword+"\n | sudo smbpasswd -a -s "+userId;`

And the updated code is,

`command = "echo -ne \""+userPassword+"\n"+userPassword+"\n\" | sudo smbpasswd -a -s "+userId;`

Thanks everyone I have got lot of clues to solve this issue.